# Cosmos DB with Mongoose - Initial connection closes but is fine after auto re-connect

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, azure-cosmosdb

I have a weird thing going on here: I'm connecting to Azure's Cosmos DB using Mongoose `5.9.7` with the following code:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

(async () => {
  mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', () => {
    console.log(new Date().toJSON(), 'disconnected!')
  })

  mongoose.connection.on('error', e => {
    console.log(new Date().toJSON(), 'error', e);
  })

  mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
    console.log(new Date().toJSON(), 'connected!')
  })

  await mongoose.connect(
    'mongodb://<DB_HOST>:<DP_PORT>',
    {
      dbName: <DB_NAME>,
      auth: {
        user: <DB_USER>,
        password: <DB_PASS>,
      },
      ssl: true,
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useFindAndModify: true,
      useCreateIndex: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    }
  )
})();
```

Now after pretty much exactly 10 seconds the client is disconnected. After another 10 seconds the auto re-connect kicks in, connects and then the connection stays stable. If I set `useUnifiedTopology` to `false` the initial connection stays alive without the disconnect after 10 secs.

Any idea what might be causing this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to connect to my cosmos db by using the code you provided,then it worked and the connection stayed stable whatever I set `useUnifiedTopology` `true` or `false`.By the way,my node.js version is `v12.16.2` and the version of mongoose is `5.9.12`.

Set `useUnifiedTopology:true`:

[image: example 1]

Set `useUnifiedTopology:false`:

[image: example 2]

The `false` option of `useUnifiedTopology` will be removed in a future version and it maybe update the newer data with an older value,so set `useUnifiedTopology:false` is not a Long-term solutions.

`UnifiedTopology:ture` use a server selection loop and retry the operation one time in the event of a retryable error.More details please refer to this [article](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.3/reference/unified-topology/).